# How to store each node in a binary search tree in a list?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a function in a binary search tree class that will return the number of nodes in the tree that have values greater than n in the form `public int greater (int n)`. I figured it might be easier to store all the values in a list and then iterate over the list and increment count each time a number is found to be greater than n. How would I go about implementing this?

This is my class so far:

```
public class BST
{ private BTNode<Integer> root;
    private int count = 0;
    List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    private BST right = new BST();
    private BST left = new BST();

    public BST()
  { root = null;
  }

  public boolean find(Integer i)
  { BTNode<Integer> n = root;
    boolean found = false;

    while (n!=null && !found)
    { int comp = i.compareTo(n.data);
      if (comp==0)
        found = true;
      else if (comp<0)
        n = n.left;
      else
        n = n.right;
    }

    return found;
  }

  public boolean insert(Integer i)
  { BTNode<Integer> parent = root, child = root;
    boolean goneLeft = false;

    while (child!=null && i.compareTo(child.data)!=0)
    { parent = child;
      if (i.compareTo(child.data)<0)
      { child = child.left;
        goneLeft = true;
      }
      else
      { child = child.right;
        goneLeft = false;
      }
    }

    if (child!=null)
      return false;  // number already present
    else
    { BTNode<Integer> leaf = new BTNode<Integer>(i);
      if (parent==null) // tree was empty
        root = leaf;
      else if (goneLeft)
        parent.left = leaf;
      else
        parent.right = leaf;
      return true;
    }
  }

  public int greater(int n){ //TODO
      return 0;
  }
}

class BTNode<T>
{ T data;
  BTNode<T> left, right;

  BTNode(T o)
  { data = o; left = right = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a list as temporary storage.

There is a concept called [Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) allowing you to visit each node of your tree.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
preorder(node)
  if (node = null)
    return
  visit(node)
  preorder(node.left)
  preorder(node.right)
```

The `visit` function here is executed exactly once at each node.
For a specialized traversal like the counting you described, you could just replace `visit` with the functionality you want, like:

```
if (node.data > n) {
    count += 1
}
```

Even better would be if you implement a `Preorder` class which you can extend to provide it with a custom visit function.